# Highlight selected item in "ListFragment"?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have posted the same problem a couple of times but it hasn't yet been resolved. I have a `ListFragment` and I want to highlight the selected item in the list. I have been given suggestions to use a "selector". I don't understand how to use this selector. My `ListFragment` class is:

```
// Create an adapter with list of stores and populate the list with
        // values
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, StoreList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * Handles the event when an item is clicked on left pane, performs action
     * based on the selection in left pane
     *  
     * @see android.app.ListFragment#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,
     * android.view.View, int, long)
     */
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String selectedStore = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLUE));
            // passes selectedStore to detail fragment  
            fragment.setText(selectedStore);

            // getItemList(selectedStore);

        }
```

Using setBackground sets the color permanently, but I want it to go away when another item is selected. 
I understand how to use a selector in a `ListView` but in my case if I haven't defined any xml for the `Listview`, then how would I use a "selector"? I am using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is predefined.

Comment: The concept of "selection" in Android for a `ListView` is for use with D-pads, trackballs, arrow keys, and other pointing devices. On tablets, there is a related concept of an "activated" row, designed to highlight the last-tapped-upon item from the touchscreen, to provide context for something adjacent to it (e.g., master-detail pattern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't getting what I wanted so I kept on digging and came up with a "cheap" solution which might not be the best practice but does the job. 
I wanted the item to be highlighted when selected and the color should go away when other item is selected from the listFragment. 
This is what worked for me- I defined a static `View V;` 
and initialized it `V = new View(getActivity());`
Then inside my

onListItemClick(ListView l, **View v**, int position, long id)

```
            V.setBackgroundResource(0);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.BLUE);
            V = v;
```

Comment: Might even call it bad practice instead of 'not the best practice'; storing a view, which keeps a reference to the activity, in a static object. Thereby leaking the activity.

Comment: You will have a problem when the list grows larger than the screen. Because the same view will be reused for previously hidden items, when they are displayed and thus some of them can be shown "selected".

Comment: @Stefan I have that problem. Do you know how to fix that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442067/list-item-wont-stay-selected-despite-setting-necessary-properties

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me for:

**res/color/menu_highlight.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red"  />
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/red" />
  <item 
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

**res/values/colors.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

**res/layout/menuitem.xml::** (XML for every item in the list)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmenu"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:background="@color/menu_highlight"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, in the ListFragment class, add View previous and add the following code to the onlistitemclick function.. (mentioned in [ListFragment: highlight selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115559/listfragment-highlight-selected-row))

```
public class MenuListFragment extends ListFragment{

View previous;

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); 
       //Logic to highlight selected item
        previous.setSelected(false);
        v.setSelected(true);
        previous=v;
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like it will suffer from the same problem Stefan mentioned on the accepted answer:  You will have a problem when the list grows larger than the screen. Because the same view will be reused for previously hidden items, when they are displayed and thus some of them can be shown "selected".

Answer (score 6):

From your `ListView`, call `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)`. Then, whenever you want to highlight a selected item, call `setItemChecked(index, true)`.

Comment: This is not working if you use custom adapter with custom list item layout.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the same and I didn't find any good solution.
What I actually do is using this code to set the listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        list_adapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        listView.invalidate();
    }
});
```

where the list adapter defines the following public methods

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = GuiBuilder.createHeroListItemView(heroes.get(position),getContext(),parent,false);
    if(position == selected_pos){
        rowView.setBackgroundColor((rowView.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_selected_color)));
    }
    return rowView;
}

public void setSelectedPosition(int selected_pos){
    this.selected_pos = selected_pos;
}

public int getSelectedPosition(){
    return selected_pos;
}
```

That is, I change the background of the list item programmatically.
Moreover to avoid the blinking effect when clicking the list element I don't define any selector for the pressed state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_focused_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_default_color" />
</selector>
```

This works as intended for me. I didn't find any better solution since setSelected(true) doesn't work on list items!

Comment: It looks fine, will try this out and let you know what I found.

Answer (score 3):

This worked very nice for me in the `ListFragment`, but I think it works only for Android 4.0 and up. I created a simple layout for the list item with `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` (in case of Android below 4.0 you need to ceate the similar one in drawables):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/double_view_margin" />
```

And then, just create a simple `ArrayAdapter` using this layout and set the choice mode to single:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> labelsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item_simple_list_item, R.id.list_item_text, labels);

setListAdapter(labelsAdapter);

getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

After that you can hightlight the necessary item with `setItemChecked` method:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, final long id) {
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

Comment: If you don't override `onListItemClick`, then the `ListFragment` will automatically set that item as checked.  Or just make sure to call `super.onListItemClick(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

i code

```
getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
```

after

```
setListAdapter(oAdapter);
```

code block

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to type-a1pha but with the selectors, once you have the view you can view.setSelected(true) and that would add the style you have defined on your selector. 
you need to remove the flag once the action is performed.