# Need to change the background of listitem out of getView() in android

Tags: android, listview, background

I have list view. while setting the listitems through adapter, I have set background for a item at particular position in getView(). When I click the listitems, I need to set background for that item as well as remove the background of the item which i have set in the getView() of the adapter class. I have achieved  to set background while clicking the listitem. But I can't remove the background which I set in the getView(). I am running out of time. Need help.

Listclick:

```
View lastView;

     lv_school.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pa, View v, int pos,long row1) {
    if(lastView==null){                       
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);                      
    lastView=v;
    }
    else{
    lastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                          
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);
                                lastView=v;
                                }

                        }
                    });
```

And my adapter class is:

```
public class SchoolAdapterSetting extends BaseAdapter {
            private Activity activity;
            List<String>data=new ArrayList<String>();
            private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            public SchoolAdapterSetting(Activity a, List<String> school_name_List) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                activity = a;
                data = school_name_List;

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi = convertView;

                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.school_item, null);
                final TextView info = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.schl_text);
                Typeface type1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CORBEL.TTF"); 
                info.setTypeface(type1);
                if(position==5)
                {
                    info.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);
                    pressedView=vi;
                }
                info.setText(data.get(position));
                return vi;
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't know, why this question get down vote?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar and developed my own logic to implement it. My code is for highlighting the currently selected ChildView and if you see the code, you can implement it for both ParentView and ChildViews.

```
    public int _groupPosition = -1;
    View _lastColored;
    private int _highlightedGroup = -1;
    private int _highlightedChild;



    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        _groupPosition = groupPosition;
        _highlightedGroup = groupPosition;
        _highlightedChild = childPosition;
        if (_lastColored != null) {
            _lastColored.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        _lastColored = v;
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(214, 214, 214)); // whatever colour you want to set
             ..... // your code here
}
```

**NOTE :** The above code is for ExapandableListView but I am sure you can modify it to your own requirements.

No need to use any selectors in your XML file. This code does it all. Good luck!

Comment: please read my question carefully. I have also done highlighting on itemclick. I have set the item background in getView() method and i want to set to white background while clicking a different item in the list.

Comment: `if (_lastColored != null) {
            _lastColored.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the background by calling `V.setBackgroundResource(0)` on your view.

I ran into a similar situation so devised a solution to serve my needs. Do check it, might be helpful for you. [Link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132156/398802).

Answer (score 0):

> I am running out of time. Need help.

Stack Overflow should never be your last ditch attempt to get help and this looks a lot like *homework*, your question ought to have the `homework` tag.

Anyway, your `getView()` is horribly inefficient. Please watch Android's [Romain Guy explain adapters and getView()](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html). But it does work.

---

**To fix your immediate problem:** I noticed `pressedView` is saved as the first "selected" row, as long as you declare `pressedView` like this:

```
public class SchoolAdapterSetting extends BaseAdapter {
    public View pressedView;
    ...
```

Then the solution is easy:

```
if(lastView==null){
    ((SchoolAdapterSetting) pa.getAdapter()).pressedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);                      
    lastView=v;
}
else{
    lastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                          
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);
    lastView=v;
}
```

Viola!

---

**Pro-Tips:**
Do you notice how two out of the three lines in each of the if-else blocks are identical? You can pull those out.

And if you set `pressedView` to `lastView` immediately after initializing your adapter:

```
SchoolAdapterSetting adapter = new SchoolAdapterSetting(...)
lastView = adapter.pressedView;
```

then you can remove the if-else entirely!

Comment: thanks for your answer. But its not working. still I have the item highlighted in the getView() having the background, while clicking the other items.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it. I cleared the listitems using `lv_school.setAdapter(null);` and called the adapter again.
here is my code.

```
    lv_school.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pa, View v, int pos,
                            long row1) {

                        lv_school.setAdapter(null);
                        schl_adapter = new SchoolAdapterSetting(Setting.this,
                                school_name_List, pos);
                        lv_school.setAdapter(schl_adapter);
                        schl_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        lv_school.setSelection(pos);
                        spinner_selected_school_name = school_name_List.get(pos);
                        spinner_selected_school_id = schooltagid_List.get(pos);

                    }
                });


public class SchoolAdapterSetting extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        public View pressedView;
        private int highlight_pos;
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public SchoolAdapterSetting(Activity a, List<String> school_name_List,
                int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            activity = a;
            data = school_name_List;
            highlight_pos = pos;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.school_item, null);
            final TextView info = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.schl_text);
            Typeface type1 = Typeface
                    .createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CORBEL.TTF");
            info.setTypeface(type1);
            if (position == highlight_pos) {
                info.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selected);
            }
            info.setText(data.get(position));
            return vi;
        }

    }
```