# ListFragment Selected Item

Tags: android

i have a ListView on a ListFragment that use SimpleCursorAdapter to generate my list. i wanted to highlight selected item in my ListView, i've tried :

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listselect_light_blue);
```

in  onListItemClick but it works odd and it selects two row when i click one of items and i want it to be single , i also set Choice Mode

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:choiceMode="singleChoice"   
           android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            />
```

i've tried ListSelector but when i click on an item it doesn't highlight until i scroll the list and it turn highlighted.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.listview_selector);

}
```

and :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/listselect_light_blue" />
</selector>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130266/highlight-selected-item-in-listfragment

Comment: @Rachel : i've used "Ayush"'s answer but two row's of  my list got selected when scrolling! i don't know why

Comment: try the alternative answers..

Comment: @Rachel : invalidate() didn't work and because of SimpleCursorAdapter inside of ListFragment i couldn't use getView().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way if you want to highlight selected item in `Listview`.

This works for me.

First set Adapter in Listfragment before use setSelector(..).

```
 setListAdapter(mAdapter);
 getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.fragment_listselector);
```

**fragment_listselector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_activated="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_active_pattern"  />
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_pattern" />
</selector>
```

when onItemClick(..) is called put this code.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {   
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
            getListView().setSelection(position);
            getListView().setSelected(true);

    }
```

Comment: i have onListItemClick in ListFragment,and i can't use onItemClick,so i try your work and in selector i replaced a color in your state_activated,and transparent in another,but it doesn't show highlight

Comment: finally i fixed my issue with a custom adapter and implementing change background color in getView() function,Ty for your solution

Comment: Just to help future readers, but this won't work if your target api is set below 11. one of the compatibility features is interfering.