# change List Item (image) on selected, activated, pressed android

Tags: android, listview

I'm using navigation drawer as a sliding menu and have custom listview which has one textview and one image. I want to change the image on select, pressed, activated. I can change background etc but don't know how to change the item image itself. Please help.

Comment: use this for your activity or fragment http://stackoverflow.com/a/14475868/1935890 & for selected position use custom ArrayAdapter class & in this getView(..) method check position of selected & make check for selection.

Comment: sorry i could not understand, would you please post some code?