# ListFragment: highlight selected row

Tags: android, selector

I am using ListFrament and I want to highlight selected rows.

My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/gold" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/plum" />
  <item 
    android:drawable="@color/medium_green" />
</selector>
```

The code in my ListFragment: 
in onCreateActivity:

```
this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

on click:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
    String tag = this.getTag();
    Log.d(TAG, "id, position " + id + " " + position);
    list.setSelection(position);
}
```

unfortunately this does not work - it only blinks "gold", when clicking the row... I want that the selected row stays highlighted...

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Comment: You will have to do it through the adapter. Adapter is the one responsible for rendering the list items.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

set a Global Variable of your row type. I am taking View as it is generic

```
View previous;
```

initialize view in onCreateView

```
previous=new View(getContext);
```

And when onListItemClick 
  do like this

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
    String tag = this.getTag();
    Log.d(TAG, "id, position " + id + " " + position);
   previous.setSelected(false);
   v.setSeleted(true);
   previous=v;
}
```

Try this and Get back to I have used this in my old apps... I will work for sure.. I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer - unfortunately it did not work for me - based on your idea I tried:  previous.setSelected(false);
  previous.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
  
  v.setSelected(true);
  v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.plum);
  previous = v; - it does not look nice, but it works

Comment: Good to know it helps you..Change your selector code... remove     android:state_pressed="true" item...it will work...You can mark this as answer if it helps you...